# summarise mean median data frame R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with Fst values for different SNPs windows.

I would like to summarise the mean and median of the Fst values for each gene windows:

```
gene chr    start Nsites     Fst01    Fst02    Fst12


1     AC002310.7  16 30591000      2       1       8.      5
2         ZNF785  16 30591000      2       1       30     1
3     AC002310.7  16 30593000      2       2       4.     10
4         ZNF785  16 30593000      2       3       20.    2
5     AC002310.7  16 30595000      2       3       2.     20
6         ZNF785  16 30595000      2       6.      10.    3
```

Output:

```
      gene           n   Fst01    Fst02    Fst12     
1     AC002310.7     3    2.        4.      10
2         ZNF785     3    3.       20       2
```

I wrote something like this:

```
df %>% summarise_at(group_by(df, gene), vars(Fst01, Fst02,Fst12), funs(n(),mean))
```

but it is giving me the following error:

```
Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not list
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Any help, highly appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a pipe the object on the left hand side is passed in as the first argument to the function on the right hand side, so you would do:

```
df %>% group_by(gene) %>%  summarise_at(vars(Fst01, Fst02,Fst12), funs(n(),mean))
```

In this way the first argument to `group_by` is `df` and the first argument to `summarise_at` is `df` grouped by `gene`